# Check user roles from Application Service

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

i'm implementing Application Service that sends statistical data to home page (dashboard application page).

Based on User's Role (the service needs authentication) i would extract/aggregate data from database using WhereIf() based on is role

In particular if user is  administrator, I will not apply a data extraction filter using WhereIf()

To do that i've injected IAbpSession inside service constructor to be able to give userid, but how can i ckeck if user is an administrator?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check if current user is an administrator by checking the associated roles of that user. You must inject the `UserManager` which has several methods for role checking. One of them is `IsInRole(userId, roleName)`.

Comment: OMG ... yes, it's right!
I had already injected the UserManager but i didn't see the existence of IsInRole method
Tnx

Comment: maybe the name of the method change to IsInRoleAsync

Comment: What about getting ALL the roles for a user, given the userId?